# app engine cannot find images

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, playn

I am developing a html5 game using PlayN. It works well in Eclipse.(Both java application and html). But after I deployed it to app engine, there always are 5 pictures cannot be found. Does anyone know the reason?

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Please specify some more details. What images are not being found, relevant html/css code, app.yaml configuration, logs, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Shy of more information, the usual reason for such problems is that image files are either configured to get resources (which renders the inaccessible to HTTP), or as static-files (which renders them as being inaccessible to the app to open).

Comment: Thanks! I finally got the problem...In dev mode, the path is not case sensitive, but in app engine, it's case sensitive...